# Retrieving Notes and Attachments related to a custom object in a single SOQL query

Tags: soql, notes

I want to retrieve Notes And Attachments that are attached with the record of a custom object in a single query .How can i do this?

```
SELECT Id,Name,(SELECT Id,Title FROM Notes),
               (SELECT Id,Name FROM Attachments) 
  FROM My_Custom_Object__c WHERE id='01a4s7dfsaawZAE'
```

i have tried to solve it using the above query but through this i am not able to acces notes and attachments in apex.if i run this query in developer console it is showing me the notes and attachments of that record.How can i access same in apex.

Comment: when i am running query SELECT Id,Title FROM Note WHERE ParentID ='a06J0000004SKaa' in developer console it is returning 1 row correctly.but the same query when i am running in apex it is giving null.what's the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have applied `with sharing` in class declaration and that particular record would not be accessible to respective user. that is why you can see records in developerr console but getting null in apex code. `with sharing` enforce the sharing rules that apply to the current user.

To know more about `with sharing`  [Click Here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm)